# GPG Error (Trusty 14.04)

Tags: apt, gnupg

Every time I try to run `sudo apt-get update` I get the following after Reading Package Lists:

```
W: GPG error: http://repos.codelite.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6856E1DB1AC82609.
```

I have been looking everywhere and have found an identical problem [here](https://github.com/eranif/codelite/issues/467), but this solution did not work for me.

Comment: Have you tried adding the key manually with `sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc`?

Comment: Go ahead and mark the problem as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you need to fetch the CodeLite developer key.

Try adding the key manually with

```
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc
```

After you do this, go ahead and try reinstalling the package you were installing.

[Source](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/WxWidgets30Binaries#toc2)